# Cast interface with generic type parameter extending Comparable

Tags: java, generics

I have got a very simple interface with a generic type parameter.

```
public interface Foo<T> {
    void add(T element);
}
```

Now, i have a variable of this interface in a class like this:

```
public class Bar {

    private Foo<?> foo;

    public void action() {
        Object o = new Object();
        (Foo<Object> foo).add(o); // in my case i know that this will work
    }
}
```

But now, if i modify the interface so that the type parameter must extend `Comparable<T>`, how can i achieve the same effect as above?

```
public interface Foo<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    void add(T element);
}

public class Bar {

    private Foo<?> foo;

    public void action() {
        Object o = new Object();
        // compiler error, since Object does not extent Comparable
        (Foo<Object> foo).add(o);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I have a lot of classes implementing this interface, for example:

```
public class IntFoo implements Foo<Integer> {

    public void add(Integer element) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

In my `Bar` class i have a `Foo<?>` and i want to add elements to it using `add()`. I have taken precautions (for example with `instanceof`) to only add an `Integer` if it is of type `Foo<Integer>`.

Comment: I think that your understanding of interfaces is a bit wrong. First of all where is the concrete implementation of your interface? Secondly what do you mean by store an instance of this interface?

Comment: @Aris_Kortex Does the implementation matter?

Comment: You can do `((Foo) foo).add((Comparable)o);`. But this looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why use a generic interface and then work around the generics?

Comment: It does, doesn't? Also why do you want the interface to extend `Comparable`?

Comment: *in my case i know that this will work*... depends what you mean by "work". The reason the compiler gives you a warning there is because it might *appear* to work and then blow up when you're least expecting it.

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks for the replies so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why your approach is not working out the way you expect, you have to first understand the wildcard you're using - `?`, and a little background on generics vs. casting.

A generic with wildcard is regarded as a "don't-care" or ["unknown" type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html); that is to say, you neither know *nor* care what type is in that generic, since due to type erasure, you can't retrieve it later on.

Generics were introduced to spare us the hassle or need to cast to a specific type that we wanted.  We could define a homogeneous type and simply deal with *that* as opposed to having to cast every time.  Generics allow us to deal with mismatched typings as a result of a bad cast at **compile time**, meaning that the code won't even compile if Java believes it to be a bad type cast.

Since casts are the only way for a developer to usurp control from the compiler, if you cast, you're telling the compiler that you know what you're doing.  If you *don't*, you'll get a **runtime** exception.

---

All of that to say...

The *only* way you're going to get any element of type `Comparable` into `Bar` is if you have a typed and bound generic.

```
public class Bar<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Foo<T> {

    private Foo<T> foo;

    public void add(T object) {
        foo.add(object);
    }
}
```